# SalesForce Objects without Timestamp Values

Tags: support

I am trying to achieve Incremental load from Salesforce.com to my Oracle DEV instance.For most of the tables i have createddate with timestamp to apply my logic for pulling latest records, but for other tables there are no Timestamp values seen. Could you please let me know how to identify latest records from Salesforce.com table which doesn't have Timestamp values ? Eg : ACCOUNTPARTNER,ACCOUNTSHARE,OPPORTUNITYFEED

Answer (score 0):

AccountPartner has SYSTEMMODSTAMP, CREATEDDATE, and LASTMODIFIEDDATE

AccountShare has LASTMODIFIEDDATE

OpportunityFeed has SYSTEMMODSTAMP, CREATEDDATE, and LASTMODIFIEDDATE

Basically, every object in Salesforce has at least one date field on it - you can count on that.

Comment: After pulling data from SFDC, We dont find SYSTEMMODSTAMP, CREATEDDATE, and LASTMODIFIEDDATE for Account Partner. LASTMODIFIEDDATE for AccountShare. SYSTEMMODSTAMP, CREATEDDATE, and LASTMODIFIEDDATE for OpportunityFeed.

Comment: What will you suggest if any of the SFDC table dont have values for SYSTEMMODSTAMP, CREATEDDATE, and LASTMODIFIEDDATE? What is the mechanism to check Latest record for those tables?

Comment: I would guess then that you have a field-level security problem, because those fields exist on those objects. All Salesforce objects that I am aware of have a datestamp on them.

Comment: After pulling data from SalesForce to our local Database later sometime some of the records are been deleted in SF. Can we know how to get the "deleted" list with the Deletion TimeStamp on each record?

Comment: The ISDELETED field on the record tells you whether the record has been deleted - when this is true, the record has been marked for deletion (and is in the Recycle Bin). The SYSTEMMODSTAMP field tells you when the record was deleted. Keep in mind that records stay in the Recycle Bin for a limited amount of time and may have been hard-deleted if you wait too long.

Comment: Another option is to use the getDeleted() API call to "to retrieve a list of records that have been deleted from your organization’s data within the specified timespan.": https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_getdeleted.htm

Comment: ISDELETED Field says 0 or 1. How to check the Deleted record from the SF Table when it is physically deleted?

Comment: Also please suggest to access "Recycle Bin" for checking deleted records in SF.

Comment: What about FeedAttachment? It doesn't seem to have any.